# How can I customize steps run during ionic app-scripts build?

Tags: ionic2, tslint

I want to start using tslint 4, but the ionic app-scripts does not support it yet: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/649

I have successfully configured the lint script (in package.json) to run `ng lint` instead of `ionic-app-scripts lint` when running `npm run lint`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    ...
  }
```

However, this change does not impact the build script. The build still runs with `ionic-app-scripts lint` instead of `ng lint`.

Is it possible to configure which commands are run in the build script?

Answer (score 0):

Event this question is quite old here is an attempt to this which i always use as it worked for me in different projects:

**Chaining of scripts**

In your case you could either add the lint to the build or create a new script which does both.

Adding the lint to the build:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng lint && ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ng lint",
}
```

Creating a new one:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "linted-build": "npm run lint && npm run build"
}
```

Make sure you use `&&` to not execute the next script. --> So that build gets not executed if linting failed. If you want to continue anyway you can use a single `&`.
Hope this information will help you ;)